# pycsw: How to harvest WMS and WFS endpoints into a single, combined catalogue entry?

Tags: pycsw

I want to harvest the WMS and WFS endpoints of a geoserver instance into pycsw.

Pycsw supports harvesting but as far as I can tell, I can't harvest WMS and WFS at the same time, and thus have to harvest them consecutively.

This works, but I now have 2 CSW entries for each dataset, one for the WMS and one for the WFS endpoint.

What I would like to have though is a single CSW entry for each dataset with both the WMS and WFS endpoint.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think that you can't really harvest WMS and WFS at the same time even from GeoServers. GeoServer admin can configure that some layers are available only as WMS or WFS, and raster layers are not ever available as WFS even they may be available as WCS. Combining CSW entries should happen after harvesting in my mind.

Comment: If you harvest from a WMS or WFS end point the records you get aren't really data set records, but instead service metadata.  The services act on one or more data sets, sometimes in combination ( a single WMS layer may comprise more than one data set, or conversely a WFS feature type may be only part of a single data set...).

Comment: nmtoken, user30184 : Fair points. In my simple case however each dataset has exactly 1 WFS and 1 WMS end point and I'm looking for an easy way to create CSW records that combine both into a single CSW record. Since I suspect this is not an uncommon case I'm hoping someone created a solution for it already.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I'd recommend taking a resource oriented approach instead, where you could create dataset related metadata records which have WMS/WFS links accordingly.  You could then have pycsw harvest those metadata records instead as a WAF or through the `pycsw-admin.py` tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would I have to create these metadata records manually or is there a way to automatically create them either based on the geoserver instance or the separately harvested endpoints in pycsw?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the innards of GeoServer, but assuming one can loop through GeoServer's configuration to:
- get all datasets
- create metadata foreach dataset with WMS/WFS/WCS links as applicable

You could write something pretty easily in Python leveraging [pygeometa](https://geopython.github.io/pygeometa), for example.